# Laravel/PHP how to use array map and sort

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building an app using laravel/php. I having using how to map and sort my array. Is there anyone can help me how to fix this? I have this two different array. The first picture is the label and second is my data.

I am trying to map the label to  data and sort my data to min to max
But I only did it using javascript.

[image: label]
[image: data]

Here is my sample code.

```
$arrayOfObjIssues = $arrayLabelIssues.map(function($d, $i) {
return {
    label: $d,
  data: $arrayDataIssues[$i] || 0
  };
});

  $sortedArrayOfObjIssues = $arrayOfObjIssues.sort(function($a, $b) {
    return $b.data>$a.data;
  });

$newArrayLabelIssues = [];
$newArrayDataIssues = [];
$sortedArrayOfObjIssues.forEach(function($d){
  $newArrayLabelIssues.push($d.label);
  $newArrayDataIssues.push($d.data);
});
```

How can I able to fix this? All help are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the use of Laravels collections, this is fairly simple:

```
$keys = ['B', 'C', 'A'];
$values = [1, 2, 3];

$collection = \Illuminate\Support\Collection::make($keys); // state: ['B', 'C', 'A']
$combined = $collection->combine($values); // state: ['B' => 1, 'C' => 2, 'A' => 3]
$sorted = $combined->sortKeys(); // state: ['A' => 3, 'B' => 1, 'C' => 2]

$sorted->toArray(); // to get the result back as array like shown above
```

For further reference, have a look at the available [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods).

Comment: `sortKeys()` laravel above 5.6.6 version requirements?

Comment: Possible, yes. You can use `$collection->sortBy(function ($value, $key) { return $key; })` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP we use `->` rather than `.` *dot notation*.

And if `$arrayLabelIssues` is a plain PHP array you have to first convert it to Laravel collection to be able to use its functions.

So you would do something like this:

```
$arrayLabelIssues = collect($arrayLabelIssues); // now it's a Laravel Collection object

// and you can use functions like map, foreach, sort, ...
$arrayLabelIssues->map(function($item) {
    // ... your code 
});
```

Comment: My code is having an issue `$arrayOfObjIssues` here, I don't know why.

Comment: What is a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (you dont need Laravel's Collection in particular):

```
// Create empty array that will contain $arr1 as keys and $arr2 as values
$newArray = [];
foreach($arr1 as $i => $item) {
  // Match the two arrays together. Get the same index from the 2nd array.
  $newArray[$item] = $arr2[$i];
}
// Sort the list by value
asort($newArray);
```

Comment: Is it okay if I make two `newArray[]` for label and data?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with the data. This simply sorts it min to max

Comment: I resolve it but I tried your code and it gives me a Boolean value in `asort()` so its kinda weird. Still thank you so much for your time.

Comment: yea `asort` doesnt return an array, it acts on the `$newArray`.

Answer (score 0):

in collection if it has same value then it will not map each value u can also try this

```
$keys = ['B', 'C', 'A'];
$values = [1, 2, 3];
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($keys); $i++){
            $maping[$keys[$i]] = $values [$i];
        } // output ['B' => 1, 'C' => 2, 'A' => 3]
```